# jQuery loop over list items and get the data-imgid attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are several `li` elements with a `data-id` attribute like

```
<ul>
   <li data-imgid="5" class="getMe">some text</li>
   <li data-imgid="6" class="getMe">some text</li>
   <li data-imgid="7" class="getMe">some text</li>
</ul>
```

I want to loop al the li items and get theyr id in an array so I try:

```
var array = [];
$('.getMe').each(function() {
  array.push($(this).data('imgid'));
  console.log($(this).data('imgid'));
})
```

However from the logs i can see

```
console.log($(this).data('imgid'));
```

that it returns the text

> data-imgid

How can i get the id data attributes in an array?

**Seems like i made a mistake when setting data-imgid i will remove this question,**

Comment: why use imgid just use id because you used data-id. simple

Comment: @AjayMakwana for readability the object i fill in the list has an id and and imgid

Comment: Made a mistake when setting data-imgid

Comment: The question has already been closed as arising from a typo. A moderator isn't going to unilaterally delete this on that basis, since deletion would erase the efforts of the people who answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the attribute.

```js
var array = [];
$('.getMe').each(function() {
       array.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
       console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li data-id="5" class="getMe">some text</li>
   <li data-id="6" class="getMe">some text</li>
   <li data-id="7" class="getMe">some text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.map()` method and then access the `dataset` property of each element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fbp5bcrq/)

```
var array = $('.getMe').map(function () {
    return this.dataset.imgid;
}).get();

console.log(array);
// ["5", "6", "7"]
```

Of course, you could also just use the `.attr()` method to get the value as well:

```
var array = $('.getMe').map(function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-imgid');
}).get();
```

Or without jQuery:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fdre6sna/)

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.getMe'),
    array = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function (el) {
      return el.dataset.imgid
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to replace your each by this:

```
var array = [];
$('.getMe').each(function(index, current) {
       array.push($(current).data('imgid'));
       console.log($(current).data('imgid'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this......

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li data-imgid="5" class="getMe">some text</li>
   <li data-imgid="6" class="getMe">some text</li>
   <li data-imgid="7" class="getMe">some text</li>
</ul>
<script>
var array = [];
$('.getMe').each(function() {
       array.push($(this).data('imgid'));
       console.log($(this).data('imgid'));
})
console.log($(this).data('imgid'));
console.log(array);
</script>
```

Hope this helps...